# Differences Between Android Emulator and Using an Actual Device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, sms

I am self teaching my self android and making an app for a mobile application contest. I have all my code working on an emulator with the correct permissions and for a sms text being sent to user specified contacts as well as a link to the google maps position of the user. I will be demonstrating the app on a tablet that only has WIFI and doesn't use cellular data.

My question is will I have to make any additions for the app to be able to be used on this tablet or would it work just as the emulator does?

Answer (score 2):

There are not some ultra big difference between real device and emulator but still there are some :

- You can't test onTouch events on Simulator I mean you can do it via mouse clicks but it's not the same
- Emulator use your computer CPU ram and things and application will probably run much faster on Emulator then on Real device (You should be aware of that)
- Regarding GPS and location you can simulate that on emulator almost the same as on Real Android device
- You can't get the real performance result on Emulator because it will ignore all apps running on real device, battery etc...

But generally if app is working correctly on Emulator it should work on Real device also but i suggest testing on Real device if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

From @Spirit answer below:

> Emulator use your computer CPU ram and things and application will
>   probably run much faster on Emulator then on Real device (You should
>   be aware of that)

all of my experience has shown that testing on a real device is actually leaps and bounds FASTER than using any emulator. it's much easier to debug as well.

i really recommend using a real device to test on.